# Graphviz for documentation

Tags: uml, doxygen, documentation-generation, graphviz

I noticed that doxygen uses the graphviz library for creating diagrams. Have you ever used graphviz for generating documentation? Is it worth learning the graphviz for documentation purposes outside the scope of doxygen? Or am I better off to sticking with a standard data modeling package like Visio?

I understand the merits of it as a graphing library, but for trying to represent more complex UML (or similar) is it still worth looking into?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The graphviz is very very simple language/format for creating graphs. If the capabilities are enough for you I would recommend it (Its so easy, that I would estimate the time to learn with at most 1 hour).

Comment: I agree. I don't know about documentation purposes, but I was able to generate useful graphs programmatically in half an hour. My impression is that an hour is probably reasonable for the basics.

Comment: Very poor documentation, lacks totally on examples... I don't think you really need only one hour. I'm trying the whole day now to get some simple UML things done.

Comment: RIght tool for the job: Graphviz is going to be hideously horrible to try to do UML in, because that's not what it was designed for. If you need to be able to quickly show the relationships between items, Graphviz will be great. If you have to precisely place items, you will hate life.

Comment: @Thanks, if you read the PDF intro to the dot language, I think it's pretty well organized and gives a good progression of how things work. It's not the most up-to-date source, but I think it's one of the better examples of open source documentation I've seen.

http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/dotguide.pdf

Answer (score 12):

If you're just talking about creating inheritance/collaboration diagrams like Doxygen does, it's worth investigating IDEs that will do that for you automatically. For from-scratch or hand-tuned documentation, I use [OmniGraffle](http://www.omnigroup.com/applications/OmniGraffle/) (since I'm on a Mac) which I highly recommend.

However, [GraphViz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphviz) and [DOT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_language) can be really handy, not only for documentation, but for debugging and code comprehension as well, particularly for data structures. I generally don't write DOT by hand, but automatically-generated DOT can be well worth the minimal effort.

One of the places I've found GraphViz extremely useful is for understanding and debugging binary search tree algorithms. I develop [CHDataStructures.framework](http://cocoaheads.byu.edu/code/CHDataStructures), an open-source Objective-C framework, which includes several varieties of BSTs. I implemented two methods: `-(NSString*)dotGraphString` on the parent class and `-(NSString*)dotGraphStringForNode:` on each child class. In about 30-40 lines of code (most of it at the bottom of `CHAbstractBinarySearchTree.m`), I added the ability to iteratively traverse a binary tree and create a DOT representation of it, including balancing information, coloring nodes red or black, etc. (With a little care, you can easily represent null sentinel nodes and display the tree in proper sorted order.)

In my test code, after each modification of the tree, I called -`dotGraphString` and saved the result to a .dot file, stopped there with a breakpoint, then opened that file with GraphViz, which is smart enough to re-render the DOT graph when the file is updated. This approach made it vastly easier to see what was happening in the tree and spot bugs in my implementation of a given algorithm. This approach can be adapted fairly easily for various kinds of data structures, and is generally much faster and easier than creating a UI just for visualizing the structure.

Answer (score 10):

Graphviz is not going to give you a slick graphical interface like Visio.  It will however, produce well laid out graphs.  I find it most useful when I am generating graphs automatically via a program (as in the case of doxygen).

Comment: I would say it *usually* gives you well laid-out graphs. Past a certain level of complexity, you get overlaps, etc. Graph rendering is a very difficult problem. Sometimes there is only so much you can do...  http://dysart.cs.byu.edu/CHDataStructures/inherits.html

Comment: Yes, I suppose the point is that the graph layouts in Graphviz are much better than you tend see in other programs.  Also, it gives you  control of the layout when you want or need it.

Answer (score 6):

Graphviz is most useful to generate dependency graphs (via dot) programmatically. [Visitors](http://www.hping.org/visitors/) uses it to visualize site visits; [Hadoop/Cascading](http://cascading.org/) uses it to visualize execution plan of map-reduce jobs.

Answer (score 6):

I use GraphViz extensively for documentation and often sketch out relationships or architecture diagrams using GraphViz externally then add them to extra pages in my Doxygen code using the @dot/@enddot. I've also recently started using @dotfile which has the dual benefit of keeping large dot statements out of the code docs and allowing me to continue to preview them with the GraphViz GUI.

The other big benefit with GraphViz is that the simple textual format works very well with version control. You can see changes to diagrams in your git diff which would be impossible with any binary documentation format. As I've used it more an more over the years, this is becoming a more important feature to me.

However, for UML I use a true UML tool ([Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/)) rather than stuffing around in Visio.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, graphviz is easy to learn and easy to use from within programs.

Also look at [yEd](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html) which is a good tool for working with graphs.  Unlike Visio, it will load and save a variety of formats which are easy to hand-edit or programatically-generate.  The auto-layout stuff is quite nice too.

Comment: For those that really like Visio, you can use Graphviz to output in SVG format (-Tsvg) and then read that into Visio. Which can then be edited to get exactly the desired layout. Saves a lot of grunt work.

Answer (score 3):

I've used it occasionally for illustrating state machines. graphviz is perfect for that.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with the consensus here; I get a lot of value out of Graphviz. It's really good for creating simple, and not so simple, diagrams. Software developers tend to attract graphs, not just in source code but elsewhere as well.

For example, right now in another browser window, I have our group's branching and merging strategy illustrated using a graphviz diagram (displayed using the [confluence plugin](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONFEXT/Graphviz+Plugin) BTW).

Graphviz is good for UML too. See [this tutorial](http://www.ffnn.nl/pages/articles/media/uml-diagrams-using-graphviz-dot.php); it's a good introduction to Graphviz as well.

Answer (score 2):

We use graphviz to automatically generate object diagrams as feedback of our UML verification tool. We are really happy with the results since we manage to provide a graphical result without worrying at all about the layout.

Comment: GraphViz typically lays out diagrams differently from the original (if any). As a result, I often notice details that were overlooked in the original.

Answer (score 2):

I had a go with Graphviz quite a few times, though found it quite limiting.

What I found best for manual text-entry diagrams is [Tikz](http://www.texample.net/tikz/)
I used it for [FSM's](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/automata-and-petri-nets/)

If Graphviz output satisfies your particular needs, it's probably fine.
If you are not quite happy with what it does and have some TeX experience -
have a look at Tikz. There many different packages out there, you don't
need to learn pure Tikz/PGF (which may seem quite heavy).

Answer (score 1):

FYI
Microsoft Visio addin to layout diagrams with Graphviz:
http://www.calvert.ch/graphvizio/